# Building Kernel Ridge Regression with targeting sum of multiple predicted values as target

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

Can we implement a code to have a Kernel Ridge Regression that summate some subset-based predicted values to the final target?

For example, we know that a standard case will train:
feature data X(# of samples, # of features) -> Y(# of samples)
and typical sklearn code trains direct mapping of X -> Y, accepting all features at once.

What I want to do is, training a regression model such that:
for the number of features m*n, train a mapping that:

small_x_i(# of samples, 0..m) -> small_y_i (# of samples).
(small_y_i are unrestricted)

The regression is also applied n times for subsets of X: 0..m, m..2m, ..., m * (n-1)..m * n
then, sum of small_y_i targets the final value Y(samples).

I'm trying this due to a specific restriction of my problem that the number of features I can use at once is limited. Among the whole features, there are groups of them that have the same conceptual origin, and I need to train a single regression so that the sum of predicted values from each group of features finally ends up with the target value.

I know the standard cases of KRR implementations with sklearn, but actually have no idea of how to implement the task asked above. Searching about 'sum of predicted values as targets' would not give a citable clue.

Comment: I've found that my question is similar to this problem: using keywords like 'fitting individual regression model on aggregate target data'.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289139/fit-individual-level-model-on-aggregate-level-target-data?newreg=9c6e119a1a0c47559401cd593a350de5
I'm still looking for how to implement this in Python. I'll update accordingly as I find more resources.